# What is the word when faced with a situation in which neither solution/choice is morally 'right'?

Tags: idiom-requests

A while ago I heard a word which when I looked up had the meaning of having no morally 'right' solution or choice. Since then I have forgotten the word; it has been playing on my mind ever since.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Could you edit to clarify? You tagged with an idiom request, but also wrote 'what is the word' which makes it sound like a single-word-request.

Comment: Idiomatically, you'd be [*on the horns of a (moral?) **dilemma.***](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/on-the-horns-of-a-dilemma)

Answer (score 1):

You might consider:

[**Dilemma**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dilemma): a usually undesirable or unpleasant choice

> The Fed faces this dilemma: raise interest rates and slow the economy or lower them and risk serious inflation

[**The lesser of two evils**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lesser_of_two_evils_principle): Describes the situation in which the choices one faces are undesirable, but one might be less undesirable than the other.

> The Director chose to cut the arts program rather than closing the school entirely. The budget constraints were unfortunate, but ultimately it was the lesser of two evils.

Answer (score 0):

Morally ambiguous? That came to mind immediately.

Answer (score 0):

> ***You're damned if you do and damned if you don't***.

Here's a [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/(you%27re)%20damned%20if%20you%20do%20and%20damned%20if%20you%20don%27t) definition:

> informal —used to say that in a specific situation a person can be
>   blamed or considered wrong no matter what he or she does.